# What's the name of this phemonenon in random walks?

Tags: statistics, random-walk

Given a random walker on the number line that starts at 0 that has a 50% chance of going 1 unit in either direction every step, the walker will tend to stay on one side of the line for a while before returning to the other side.

What's the name of this phenomenon, if it has one?

Comment: [arcsine law?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_arcsine_law)

Comment: That's for continuous functions, but pretty much.

Comment: Yes, the best book to read about it is the first volume of Feller.

Answer (score 0):

A discrete zero mean random walk in one dimension is recurrent; it will recross 0 infinitely often.

Comment: if the walk is infinite. If you make an experiment looking for, say, a 1000 steps, it is more often that the person will be on one side of zero.

Comment: It will cross infinitely often, but I'm referring to the theorem where it tends to take very long to cross the first time.